# Adverb between conjugated verb and infinitive?

Tags: grammaticality, difference, infinitives

> The judicial function in considering and applying statutes is one of interpretation and interpretation alone. The duty of the court in every case is **loyally** to endeavour to ascer­tain the intention of the legislature; and to ascertain that intention by reading and interpreting the language which the legislature itself has selected for the purpose of expres­sing it. [(Source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyman_Duff#Impact)

1. What's this phenomenon called? Is this placement unusual or due to  my English's primitiveness?

2. Why not situate the adverb after 'endeavour', or even split the infinitive 'to endeavour' and wedge it in between?  What are the similarities and differences due to a different position?

Comment: The author could have avoided the bugbear in other less stilted ways, of course: `The court must always dutifully endeavor to ascertain the intention of the legislature...`

Comment: Also, the infinitive is *un*conjugated; it does not reflect tense, mood, number, or person.

Comment: As @TRomano says, this is a (poorly done) attempt to avoid split infinitives and would never occur in natural language. There are no semantic differences.

Comment: [Pullum on split infinitives](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/splitinf.html): "[T]he term ‘split infinitive’ is very misleading. English doesn't **have** an infinitive form of the verb in the way a language like French does. French ***succéder*** is a single word, but English ***to succeed*** is not; it's two words. The infinitival subordinating marker ***to*** is quite distinct from the verb."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is (merely) an attempt to avoid the bugbear of a "split infinitive", i.e. "to loyally endeavor".

https://www.englishforums.com/English/BernardShawSplitInfinitive/wjlmg/post.htm

Comment: If there were such a thing as a split infinitive, this might be an explanation.

Comment: There is such a bugbear.

Comment: To my (American) ear, splitting the infinitive sounds more natural than the original post's usage.  In other words, I would rather say "The duty of the court is to loyally endeavor..." than say "The duty of the court is loyally to endeavor...".

Comment: Yes, *to boldly go* is, I think, the most common way by far of placing the adverb in American speech.